# get unexpected values using synchronize

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

I have a simple snippet of code and try to experiment a little with it, but in the next code I get unclear for me order of output data:

```
public class Main {

    static int n = 100;

    public static synchronized int decreaseValue(){
        return --n;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {


        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true){
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Thread1: "+ decreaseValue());
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        },"Thread1");
        t1.start(); 

        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while(true){
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Thread2: "+ decreaseValue());
                        Thread.sleep(2000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        },"Thread2");
        t2.start();


        while(true){
            try {
                System.out.println("Main Thread: "+ decreaseValue());
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Can not understand, why I get the such values in the next order:

Thread1: 89
        Thread2: 90
        Main Thread: 88

PLEASE PAY ATTENTION TO THE N VALUE NOT TO THE ORDER OF CALLING THREADS:

```
Thread1: 99
Thread2: 98
Main Thread: 97
Main Thread: 95
Thread2: 94
Thread1: 96
Main Thread: 92
```

Comment: What would you expect? Nothing guarantees you the order of execution of `decreasedValue()` by these different threads.

Comment: nothing guarantees  which thread will call the decreease method, but as I understand, the synchronized block should guarantee the valid order of the output values.

Comment: And, in this case, it's pointless to synchronize decrement, because arithmetic operations on base types (other than long and double) are guaranteed to be atomic.

Comment: I didn't notice that  System.out.println is not a synchronized method.

Comment: @ignis decrementing an integer is not atomic, assigning to an integer is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must have read somewhere that `synchronized` must be used to ensure proper ordering, or something similar. The word "ordering" pertains to a different concept from the one you have in mind: it means that there will always be some definite ordering to the execution of synchronized blocks. The ordering is not known in advance, but it will be there every time. Without synchronized, you won't even get that guarantee: one thread could perceive one order, another thread a different order, or not perceive any actions by other threads at all.

### About your edit:

If you are concerned about printouts happening out of order, this is because your `println` statements are outside of `synchronized` and so can interleave independently of the calls to `decreaseValue`.

Answer (score 2):

Thread runs in parallelly. You can't predict their execution order. You can set thread priority which prioritize its execution order.

Comment: nothing guarantees which thread will call the decreease method, but as I understand, the synchronized block should guarantee the valid order of the output values. It seems like while one thread in this method the other one get access to it too.

Answer (score 1):

The threads are running concurrently and nothing is imposing the order on wich they should call your `decreaseValue()` function. You would expect them to be in order since you are doing the same amount of sleep :), but as soon as a thread will start/resume from a sleep, the CPU will place the thread in a running queue (creating an execution order, this is the order that synchronize will guarantee), because of this the order of your printing depends on how the CPU will place the thread in the running queue.

The print on the console is also synchronized (but not in the same block with your decreaseValue), if you are questioning the printing order. The same logic applies to printing as the one to decrease the values.

If you would like to see the prints in the same order that the value was decremented you can move print in the `decreaseValue()` function. But this will not affect the order in how the values will be decremented.

Comment: yes, but I use synchronized block and get the next order of output values: 89,90,88 - so it looks like synchronize block doesn't work.

Comment: `synchronized` only makes sure only one thread can execute the method at a time, it does not guarantee any order.

Comment: but in this case it seems like while one thread read the n value in the decrease method, the other method get access to it too.

Comment: @barn.gumbl can you provide more details, why "it seems"?

Comment: @barn.gumbl The first three are because they endend in that order in the queue, after that the CPU is applying the logic presented in my answer. See my updated answer